# How to make Roslyn the default Compiler for ASP.NET and put it in GAC?

Tags: asp.net, roslyn

We are using ASP.NET 4.6 with website/web application projects.
We added the Roslyn Complier via Nuget Package to our website project and VS.NET updated the web.config plus added a Roslyn folder under "bin". 
Inside this folder there are a number of dlls and exe files.

The documentation specifies to gain the best ASP.NET Startup time, it is best to  Ngen and GAC the Roslyn assemblies.

I am not sure how I can use Ngen.exe or other tools to move it correct to GAC.

here is the source:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/05/12/enabling-the-net-compiler-platform-roslyn-in-asp-net-applications.aspx

See this section: Announcing the first preview of new CodeDOM Providers for .NET Compiler Platform (“Roslyn”)

Comment: If will help if you can provide a link to the source of your information.

Comment: added the source to the question.

Comment: I believe .NET 4.6 includes all the bits. About whether you can use Roslyn with previous releases, you'd better contact Microsoft support for confirmation.

Comment: I can confirm that is not the case and .NET 4.6 does not ship Roslyn as default. We added Roslyn to our project as Nuget Package and now there is a Roslyn assembly folder under "bin" folder. We want to move it to GAC so that we would not need to include the Roslyn folder in each and every project.